# Running the Jfrog X-ray database sync from the command line

Tags: shell, automation, scripting, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray

I am looking to automate the offline ruleset upgrade of jfrog Xray. Once the new ruleset upgrade files have been uploaded to the right component and vulnerability folder. Is it possible to trigger the database sync from the command line? And how would I go about doing this to add into a shell script. Thank you.

There is not much documentation on running the database sync from the command line. Only thing I can really see is to schedule the sync at a specific time. But I don’t need it to sync on a daily basis just once a month when the files have been updated.

Comment: If you would like to trigger offline DB sync manually, you can make use of the rest call 'POST <platform-url>/xray/api/v1/updates/startOfflineSync'. Hope this helps